# javascript selection with text below image not appearing

Tags: javascript

I am having problems with some code and old js. I duplicate the webpage and changed the code, but the text is not appearing under the large image when its corresponding thumbnail is selected in the new file: http://jsfiddle.net/dEW75/

```
                            <script type="text/javascript">
    function swapImage(imgID)
    {
        var itemImage   = document.getElementById('itemImage');
        var itemText    = document.getElementById('itemText');
        var itemCaption = document.getElementById('itemCaption');

        itemImage.src =              "images/finishing_touches/color_stain/textured/textured" + imgID + "_sm.jpg";

            if(imgID == 1)
            {
                itemText.innerHTML    = 'Latitude East';
                itemCaption.innerHTML = ''};

            if(imgID == 2)
            {
                itemText.innerHTML    = 'Summer Breeze';
                itemCaption.innerHTML = ''};

            if(imgID == 3)
            {
                itemText.innerHTML    = 'Winter Cherry';
                itemCaption.innerHTML = ''};

            if(imgID == 4)
            {
                itemText.innerHTML    = 'Autumn Leaves';
                itemCaption.innerHTML = ''};

            if(imgID == 5)
            {
                itemText.innerHTML    = 'Boardwalk';
                itemCaption.innerHTML = ''};

            if(imgID == 6)
            {
                itemText.innerHTML    = 'Driftwood';
                itemCaption.innerHTML = ''};

            if(imgID == 7)
            {
                itemText.innerHTML    = 'Canvas Linen';
                itemCaption.innerHTML = ''};

            if(imgID == 8)
            {
                itemText.innerHTML    = 'Linen Flaxseed';
                itemCaption.innerHTML = ''};

            if(imgID == 9)
            {
                itemText.innerHTML    = 'Silver Flannel';
                itemCaption.innerHTML = ''};

            if(imgID == 10)
            {
                itemText.innerHTML    = 'Onyx';
                itemCaption.innerHTML = ''};

                            if(imgID == 11)
            {
                itemText.innerHTML    = 'East Indian Laurel';
                itemCaption.innerHTML = ''};

                              if(imgID == 12)
            {
                itemText.innerHTML    = 'Sandalwood';
                itemCaption.innerHTML = ''};

                              if(imgID == 13)
            {
                itemText.innerHTML    = 'Nora Creek Oak';
                itemCaption.innerHTML = ''};

                                 if(imgID == 14)
            {
                itemText.innerHTML    = 'Midnight Espresso';
                itemCaption.innerHTML = ''};
                    }
    </script>
                            <h1 class="galleryTitle">Color &amp; Stain</h1>
                            <div class="subMenu">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="color_stain1.htm">solid color melamine</a> </li>
                                <li><a href="color_stain3.htm">wood tone melamine</a></li>
                                <li><a class="active" href="color_stain_textured_1.htm">textured melamine</a></li>
                                <li><a href="color_stain.htm">wood veneer</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="galleryContainer2">
                            <div class="galleryNavContainer2">
                            <div class="subtitle">
                            <p>Textured Color</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumbs">
                            <div class="pageDetail1">
                            <p>page 1 of 3</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="img">
                            <a href="javascript:swapImage(&quot;1&quot;)">
                            <img src="images/finishing_touches/color_stain/textured/textured1_th.jpg" alt="Latitude East" title="Latitude East" />
                            <span class="imgText">Latitude East</span>
                            </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="img">
                            <a href="javascript:swapImage(&quot;11&quot;)">
                            <img src="images/finishing_touches/color_stain/textured/textured11_th.jpg" alt="Summer Breeze" title="East Indian Laurel" />
                            <span class="imgText">East Indian Laurel</span>
                            </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="img">
                            <a href="javascript:swapImage(&quot;12&quot;)">
                            <img src="images/finishing_touches/color_stain/textured/textured12_th.jpg" alt="Sandalwood" title="Sandalwood" />
                            <span class="imgText">Sandalwood</span>
                            </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="img">
                            <a href="javascript:swapImage(&quot;13&quot;)">
                            <img src="images/finishing_touches/color_stain/textured/textured13_th.jpg" alt="Nora Creek Oak" title="Nora Creek Oak" />
                            <span class="imgText">Nora Creek Oak</span>
                            </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="img">
                            <a href="javascript:swapImage(&quot;14&quot;)">
                            <img src="images/finishing_touches/color_stain/textured/textured14_th.jpg" alt="Midnight Espresso" title="Midnight Espresso" />
                            <span class="imgText">Midnight Espresso</span>
                            </a>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="page">
                            <ul style="margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; text-align: center;">
                                <li class="previous"></li>
                                <li class="next"><a href="color_stain_textured.htm">page</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="imgContainer2">
                            <div class="img"><img alt="" id="itemImage" name="IMG1" /></div>
                            <div class="text" style="margin-top: 13px; padding: 2px 0px 0px;">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var imgID = "1";
    swapImage(imgID);
//-->
                            </script>
                            </div>
                            <p style="margin-right: 15px;">
                            <strong>PLEASE NOTE</strong>: Items in our gallery are selected to show the variety of
                            our products. If you don't see exactly what you have in mind, most likely we have it
                            or can order it for you.
                            </p>
                            <div style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                            <p>
                            <a href="index.htm">View our other galleries</a> &raquo;<br />
                            <a href="http://www.marketingresponse.com/closetos/contact.asp">Schedule a complimentary in-home design consultation</a> &raquo;<br />
                            <a href="../locations.htm">Visit our Chicago area showrooms</a> &raquo;
                            </p>
                            </div>
                            <script language="JavaScript"><!--
     ThisPage = Gallery;
     GroupChange("on",ThisPage);
    //-->
                            </script>
```

I need the text to appear below the large image when the thumbnail is selected like on this page: http://jsfiddle.net/qVGFV/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the element to display the text in the html.  Since it doesnt exist trying to add the text does nothing.  Add this to your div with the class="imgContainer2"

```
<p id="itemText" style="padding-bottom: 0px;"></p>
```